# Bad Bind Variable?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

Trying to compile the code below and receiving a bad bind variable error for the following variables: NEW.UTC_OFFSET, NEW.DATA_DATE, NEW.HR, NEW.HR_NUM, NEW.DATA_CODE.

```
create or replace TRIGGER INS_VALS
AFTER INSERT
ON xml_load
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (
NEW.processed = 'N'
      ) DECLARE 
Value_ID Number;
pValue_ID Number;
pCalculation_ID NUMBER;
Calculation_ID Number;
Calculation_Value_ID Number;
p_Entity_Address_ID Varchar2(50);
New_Value_ID Number;
New_Calculation_ID Number;
New_Calculation_Value_ID Number;
New_Value_Tx varchar2(50);
NEW_UTC_Offset varchar2(50);

BEGIN

Value_ID := value_value_id_seq.NEXTVAL;
New_Value_ID := Value_id;
Calculation_Value_ID :=CALCULATION_VALUE_CALCULATI329.NEXTVAL;
calculation_id := Calculation_Calculation_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;



 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(Get_Entity_Address_ID((p_Entity_Address_ID));


DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Value_ID' || Value_ID);

Insert into Value
(VALUE_ID, PRODUCT_ID, DATA_SOURCE_ID, UNIT_CD, VALUE_TX, UTC_OFFSET,     DATA_DATE, HR_UTC, HR, HR_NUM, DATA_CODE, CREATE_DT, CREATE_USER_ID)
VALUES
(Value_ID, null, null, null, :NEW.Value_Tx, :NEW.UTC_Offset, :NEW.Data_Date,     null, :NEW.hr, :NEW.hr_num, :NEW.data_code, SYSDATE, '15');

END;
```

The column in value is as follows: value_id, product_id, data_source_id, unit_cd, value_Tx, utc_offset, data_date, hr_utc, hr, hr_num, data_code, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_Dt, inactive_dt

Thanks in advance!

Comment: oh, is this question not a plsql / oracle question?

Comment: `REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD` is the default, just skip it. And delete the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` - unless you are in debugging/developing.

Comment: @B001 duly noted and changed, thanks for your input!

Comment: You've listed the columns in `value` (htough not very nicely); what are the columns in `xml_load`? Those are the ones you can references with `:new`.

Comment: Why do you generate new values for `Calculation_Value_ID` and `calculation_id` if you don't use them?

Comment: @Wernfried I am building the trigger one block at a time, those values will be used in a later insert.

Answer (score 1):

@AlexPoole pointed out that my previous answer (which I've deleted) was wrong; using a local variable with the same name as a column in an INSERT statement, while confusing (and bad practice), does not cause the trigger to fail.

I have written [a LiveSQL demo (free OTN account needed)](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/gbi1c72wyg9aozffl4354zrxr). I had to make up the table definitions but used your trigger as posted (except one thing, see below). My demo inserts a row into XML_LOAD, the trigger fires successfully and inserts a row in VALUE.

The only thing is, I had to comment out the call to  `Get_Entity_Address_ID()`.

So, if `bad bind variable` is an actual problem you have, possibly the cause is that procedure not the trigger. Or you're just using a different version of the code from the one you posted here. Or - and this is the most likely explanation - `UTC_OFFSET`, `DATA_DATE`, `HR`, `HR_NUM`, `DATA_CODE` **are not columns of the table XML_LOAD** (after all, [you do have previous form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48915668/146325) in this regard).

The `:new` namespace is used to reference columns belonging to the table which owns the trigger. Your trigger code worked for me because I defined the XML_LOAD table with all the columns referenced in your posted code. But it seems you have not.

Comment: I see you had posted another answer, and you deleted it even though it already had two upvotes. Just leaving a note here to say **thank you** to you for that. (Regardless of the question or the answer, or the reason to delete it.) I don't know if there are more than ten people on this Forum who would have done that.

Comment: @mathguy - Thanks. Actually - at the time of typing - [10580 people have deleted their own post with 3 upvotes or more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined).

Comment: Wow - better than I thought! Of course, there is a difference between `count` and `count distinct`, and I meant the `oracle` realm (the only one I know), but that is really impressive. Thank you for the link!